# Data analytics basics for a organization

Tags: data-visualization, analytical

I have no knowledge on data analytics, just trying to start. I also have no idea which tools to use, so here is my question,

If I have to build a data analytics for an organization which shows trends data, where should I start with?

To add some information about my company, I work for a SaaS based software product company, we use Kubernetes for running our microservices and AWS DynamoDB and DocumentDB as our database.

Below are the things are in my mind right now,

- Which features are used by which customer
- Most used feature
- Which customer is actively using the product?
- Which customer is not actively using the product?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for BI tools. Tools like Power BI, Tableau, Looker or SAS visual analytics.

With these tools you can perform ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) on data sources to extract and prepare the data appropriately, and use visualizations to show (for example) various trends in data.